# Problem showing English characters with xepersian

Tags: xetex, languages, xepersian

I'm using TeXstudio in order to write a report and I use XeLaTeX compiler. However the following code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\title{فارسی - English }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

fails to print the English characters and the output only contains Farsi strings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with TeXstudio as your editor but a feature of `xepersian` package. I looked at the documentation and found out that if you want to show English text for short left-to-right text, you wrap the text in `\lr{}`. If it involves larger amount of text, you use the `latin` environment. Perhaps you meant to type something like

```
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\title{\lr{-English}فارسی}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{latin}
\kant[1]
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

which gives us the following output.

[image]

I changed to `article` class here for demonstration purposes. You can switch back to `report` in your actual use case. (BTW, why the very small left and right margins?)

Comment: I appreciate your very helpful answer.